# App Store Connect "Missing Info.plist value for key 'CFBundleIconName'"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I have been dealing with the following error when attempting to upload my app to the app store for testing in TestFlight:

```
Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'Fern-Labs--Inc.fern-ios'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90713 for id ########
```

There are other stack overflow posts about this but I feel like I've tried everything in those posts and I still can't get this app to upload, even though it has successfully uploaded before!

I'm suspicious it's something to do with a mismatch in some settings that I have not been able to figure out how to find?

Here's what I've tried:

- Made sure that my app has an App Icon asset, with every slot filled in with the appropriately sized icon
- Made sure that the `App Icon Source` in General settings for the app was pointed to the correct icon assets
- Attempted to create a second different app icon asset and point to that instead just in case it was an issue with the asset for some reason, but that didn't help at all
- Tried to make sure that the app bundle name and display name match on App Store Connect
- Tried adding a `CFBundleIconName` key to Info.plist that pointed to AppIcon, didn't work
- Tried adding `CFBundleIconName` key and value AppIcon to the "info" section where plist is managed in the app's settings, didn't work
- Tried having that info in both the Info.plist file AND in the info settings, didn't work

Also, my `display name` used to be just `fern` and I changed it to `Fern Co`, things broke, and I changed it back to `fern` in my general settings on xcode

General settings:

```
Display name: Fern Co
Bundle Identifier: Fern-Labs--Inc.fern-ios
App Icons Source: AppIcon
```

App Store Connect General Info:

```
Localizable Information
Name: Fern Co

General Info
Bundle Identifier: Fern-Labs--Inc.fern-ios
```

What else can I try to fix this? I have also tried to go to the URL they link in the error message but it takes me to a broken page that says Service Unavailable. `http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7`

Comment: Do you see your app's icon in the simulator springboard?

Comment: @matt yes, I do

Comment: OK, that's significant! Is that true even after you've completely erased the simulator? How about if you switch your scheme's Run action to use the Release configuration; build and run to a totally erased simulator, do you still see the icon?